# Invoke button click programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to programmatically click button on a webpage with source like this

```
<input alt="BusiBtn" class="aButtn" type="submit" value="Search" tabindex="16">
```

When I do

```
WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
b.Navigate(URL);
while (b.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
   Application.DoEvents();
}
b.Document.GetElementByID("BusiBtn").InvokeMember("click");
```

I get "Object reference not set to an instance of object error".

Can somebody help.

Thanks
Rashmi

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in this case simply find all the `HtmlElement`s having `input` tag. If you need to invoke all the `input` tags in general, then just invoke `click` on them. And if you need only the above `input` element, then filter all the `input` tags to search for the specific tag with the attribute values like above. Please have a look at the following code:

```
HtmlElementCollection elems = b.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
{
    string altStr = elem.GetAttribute("alt");
    string classStr = elem.GetAttribute("class");
    string typeStr = elem.GetAttribute("type");
    string valueStr = elem.GetAttribute("value");
    string tabindexStr = elem.GetAttribute("tabindex");

    if((altStr == "BusiBtn") && (classStr == "aButtn") && (typeStr == "submit") && (valueStr == "Search") && (tabindexStr == "16"))
    {
        elem.InvokeMember("click");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong field.

`alt` is for alternative text.

You have not actually given that button an `id` of `BusiBtn`.

Try:

```
<input id="BusiBtn" class="aButtn" type="submit" value="Search" tabindex="16">
```

The clue is in the `GetElementByID` call.  It's not called `GetElementByAlt` for a reason ;)

Comment: That's what the source looks like. How can I invoke the button without the ID?

Comment: if the element has no id, then `GetElementByID` will not work for you.  Use another method that is available that *can* match a known value.

Answer (score 1):

add 'name' property to input tag and then use GetElementsByName property

Comment: This is not our website. I am crawling somebody's website and want to programmatically download info by clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the GetElementsByTagName method instead of GetElementById to get all Input-Elements on the page and then cycle through using GetAttribute.  An example can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx.